# jQuery ajax request doesn't get completed

Tags: apache, jquery

I'm facing a weird issue in which the ajax requests doesn't get completed when subsequent requests are made.

The ajax calls works fine when the web page is loaded first time. But if I invoke the same method without refreshing the page, then the request never get completed and even apache is not responding. I checked apache error logs and found the following entry:

```
[Tue Nov 01 16:41:42 2011] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
```

Here is the jQuery code which I am trying to execute:

```
(function($) {
    $(function(){

        form = $('form.crud');
         $("#end_date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});

/** Contract Comments **/
        $('#actionbar ul li:nth-child(1) a').colorbox({
            scrollable: false,
            innerWidth: 600,
            innerHeight: 280,
            href: SITE_URL + 'admin/contracts/comments/create_ajax',
            onComplete: function() {
                $.colorbox.resize();
                $('form#comments').removeAttr('action');
                $('form#comments').live('submit', function(e) {
                    var form_data = $(this).serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: SITE_URL + 'admin/contracts/comments/create_ajax',
                        type: "POST",
                            data: form_data,
                        success: function(obj) {
                            if(obj.status == 'ok') {
                                $.colorbox.close();
                            } else {
                                $('#cboxLoadedContent').html(obj.message + obj.form);
                                $('#cboxLoadedContent p:first').addClass('notification error').show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

It seems the browser is flooding the server with redundant requests. Does it makes sense to increase the MaxClients count(currently it is 256 for prefork MPM and 300 for worker MPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you're effectively flooding you webserver. You should use a tool like Firebug or Chrome developers tools and have a look at the number of ajax requests you are sending.

I beg the live event in `$('form#comments').live('submit', function(e) {` is running several times (check it with a `console.log('attaching live event');`). Try to avoid live events or at least add a class in your binded event element so that you could filter your live event selector to avoid binding an already binded one.

This should work:

```
$("form#comments:not(.live-submit-binded)")
   .addClass('live-submit-binded')
   .live('submit', function(e) {
    (...)
});
```

Comment: I added the console.log to the live function and re-tested it. Here is the behaviour I found: During the first request, everything is working fine with a single request and the colorbox got closed after completing the ajax request. The second request also completed, but this time two requests were sent to the server. The third request didn't got completed at all. I need to get better understanding of live() method and then get back to you.